# Cannot change default scopes requested by Google Identity Platform for OIDC

Tags: google-identity

We have an identity provider based on OpenID connect which we want to use in Google Identity platform (GIP). The owner of this identity provider allows only the scopes `openid` and `email`. So we configured our frontend code to only request those two scopes. When we tested authentication via this provider, we received an error response:

> Error getting verification code from oidc.production response: error=invalid_scope

In this text `oidc.production` is the name of the OIDC provider configured in GIP. We verified the scopes and also checked our network tab, to be 100% sure no additional scopes were requested by us.

The owner of the provider sent us some audit logs from their side and then we realized that not we are requesting more scopes than necessary, but GIP does:

> Requested scopes: **openid email profile** openid email

So the ones we requested explicitly (openid email), are postfixed to the ones GIP requests by default it seems.

The [OIDC spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#Scopes) defines `openid` to be the only required scope. I get that `email` might be needed as well, but the behavior we see seems to be clearly off spec.

Can anybody confirm this behavior? Does anybody know a workaround? We really do not need access to the `profile` scope and the owner of the provider is not willing to allow it for us.